# reset Activity android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

my 1st page have a spinner, that will parse value to the 2nd activity.. I set onBackPressed on the 2nd page to go back to my home page, but the problem is, the spinner selection is not being reset.. why?

Comment: Why would it be reset? You need to handle it in your Activity's onResume() or onActivityResult()

Comment: what you would like to ask? Do you want to reset the spinner to default?

Comment: In your Ist page, you create a variable and store the spinner selected value. And, in same page, under onResume method you just assign that value to spinner. May be it will works..

Comment: I just want to restart my 1st activity when I press back key on 2nd page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return from activity B to activity A, the onRestart method in activity A will be called.
You can override that method and clear you spinner there.

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
   //clear your spinner here... spinner.setSelection(0) or something..
   super.onResume();
}
```

Here is an explanation:

> onRestart : Called after your activity has been stopped, prior to it being started again.
>   Always followed by onStart()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It will refresh your 1stActivity

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    startActivity(getIntent());
}
```

**EDIT**

**EXPLANATION**

You can see the [Lifecycle of the Android here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

When your going from first Activity to second Activity `OnPause()` method is called. Same when you coming back to your first activity from second activity `onResume()` method will be called.

There is two way to reset your Spinner

**First One**

As you asked restarting your first activity by this method

```
startActivity(getIntent()); // It refresh your activity
```

More Detail of `startActivity(getIntent())`

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,FirstActivity.class)
startActivity(refresh);
```

**Second Way**

```
 Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourSpinnerId);
 yourSpinner.setSelection(0);// Which reset Spinner to default
```

Hope it helps

Comment: further explain? I want to learn something, I'm tired of copy and paste and make thing works :D

Comment: Edited my answer check it now

Comment: I called first method inside my second activity, not working, it getting worse, the app doesn't seem right..

Comment: No you don't need to do anything in your second activity. Just put the code in your first activity it should work

Answer (score 0):

set Adapter in onStart method of the application, or invoke notifyDataSetChanged() method in onStart() method.

Comment: I only see onCreate and what is Adapter?